# Do event.target.files[0] needs to be true if event.target.files is true?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

```
const onImageChange = (e) => {
        if (e.target.files && e.target.files[0]) {
            let img = e.target.files[0];
            e.target.name === "profileImage" ? setprofileImage(img) : setcoverImage(img);
        }
};
```

My doubt is why we need to check for e.target.files[0] when e.target.files is already true?
Because e.target.files is the entire array of files then why do we need to check for the 0th index of it to proceed with the handlechange.

Comment: What do you think the truthiness of an empty array is?

Comment: Yup its true event if the array is empty.And it cleared my doubt of why we should'nt check the first index directly because when the user does not upload any files the event.target.files will not be there and it will produce an error most probably. Correct me if I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In situations where the event.target.files isn't an array or a string, if you only check event.target.files then something like a a true boolean would pass the check, however if you also check event.target.value[0] it would return undefined and would fail the condition. If it should always be an array use the following

```
const onImageChange = (e) => {
        if (Array.isArray(e.target.files) {
            let img = e.target.files[0];
            e.target.name === "profileImage" ? setprofileImage(img) : setcoverImage(img);
        }
};
```

Comment: What changes do you suggest inorder to accept only image files from the user?

Comment: Sorry I edited the above answer to exclude my thoughts on the type of the array element and the dangers of not checking that type in the following setprofileImage() and setcoverImage(). you can always check the file type. take a look at this source. https://roufid.com/javascript-check-file-image/